# Making Code O(256)?

Tags: python, algorithm, time

> **Problem Statement ([HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/countercode/challenges/subset))**
>
> You have a list of integers, initially the list is empty.
>
> You have to process Q operations of three kinds:
>
> - add s: Add integer s to your list, note that an integer can exist more
>     than one time in the list
> - del s: Delete one copy of integer s from the list, it's guaranteed
>     that at least one copy of s will exist in the list.
> - cnt s: Count how many integers a are there in the list such that a AND
>     s = a, where AND is bitwise AND operator
>
> **Input Format**
>
> First line contains an integer Q.  Each of the following Q lines
>   contains an operation type string T and an integer s.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - 1 ≤ Q ≤ 200000
> - 0 ≤ s < 2<sup>16</sup>
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each **cnt s** operation, output the answer in a new line.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 7 
> add 11 
> cnt 15 
> add 4 
> add 0 
> cnt 6 
> del 4 
> cnt 15
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 1 
> 2 
> 2
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> For first line, we have 15 AND 11 = 11 so the answer is 1
>
> For second line, 6 AND 0 = 0 and 6 AND 4 = 4 so the answer is 2
>
> For third line, 4 has been deleted and we have 15 AND 11 = 11 and 15
>   AND 0 = 0 so the answer is 2

**My working code:**

```
operations = int(raw_input())
current = 1
lst = []
while current <= operations:
    count = 0
    input_ = raw_input().split()
    operation = input_[0]
    num = int(input_[1])
    if operation == 'add':
        lst.append(num)
    elif operation == 'cnt':
        for number in lst:
            if number & num == number:
                count += 1
        print(count)
    elif operation == 'del':
        lst.remove(num)
    current += 1
```

**Somewhat Optimized Solution: [CodeReview Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98803/performing-operations-on-a-list/98854#98854)**

```
operations = int(raw_input())
nums = set()
storage = [0] * (2 ** 16)

for _ in xrange(operations): 
    input_ = raw_input().split()
    operation = input_[0]
    num = int(input_[1])

    if operation == 'add':
        nums |= {num}
        storage[num] += 1
    elif operation == 'cnt':
        print(sum(
            storage[number]
            for number in nums
            if (number & num) == number
        ))
    elif operation == 'del':
        storage[num] -= 1
```

I understood the above code and the optimizations that were made.

**The Code that I don't understand:**

```
q = input()
def init():
    global a
    a = [0 for i in range(1000000)]

def add(s):
    for i in range(1 << 8):
        if (i&s) == 0:
            a[s|i] += 1

def delete(s):
    for i in range(1 << 8):
        if (i&s) == 0:
            a[s|i] -= 1
def cnt(s):
    res = 0
    for i in range(1 << 8):
        if (s|(i<<8)) == s:
            res += a[s & (~(i<<8))]
    return res

init()
for _ in range(q):
    c,s = map(str,raw_input().split())
    s = int(s)
    if c == "add":
        add(s)
    elif c == "del":
        delete(s)
    elif c == "cnt":
        print cnt(s)
```

I am unable to understand how the author of this code makes it O(256) using the given operations.

The above code is one of the two accepted submissions in Python according to the leaderboard. The 2nd Solution (pretty similar to the one above) : [HackerRank Solution](https://codepair.hackerrank.com/paper/c5Rpe2pr?b=eyJyb2xlIjoiY2FuZGlkYXRlIiwibmFtZSI6IkRhcnRoU2hhZG93IiwiZW1haWwiOiJhbmFnaGsuZG9zQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJ9)

Comment: What does O(256) mean? If you're talking about big O notation, AFAIK the only number that can appear by itself in those parentheses is 1.

Comment: It is big O notation. I have understood from the code that the complexity for the algorithm used is O(256).

Comment: @Kevin Not exactly true, but any number on its own is equivalent to 1.

Comment: O(256) doesn't make much sense, where did you get it?

Comment: Frankly, another person on CodeReview told me that the above program was O(256). If it is not, you may edit the post accordingly.

Comment: It's `O(q)`, it's just that each operation is `O(1)` with a constant factor of around 256.

Comment: @JonasWielicki, any number bigger than zero, that is. :)

Comment: @Kay Touché, that’s correct of course ☺

Answer (score 4):

The program is actually `O(q)`, with each one of the `q` operations processed in `O(1)`, with a constant factor of `256 = 2^8 = 8 bits`. `O(256)` is a clutch / informal way of saying that.

Since `s` is at most `2^16`, we can solve the problem by only storing the first `16` bits of each number. That would go something like this:

```
def add(s):
    a[s & ((1 << 16) - 1)] += 1 # only save the first 16 bits

def delete(s):
    a[s & ((1 << 16) - 1)] -= 1 # only remove the first 16 bits

def cnt(s):
    res = 0
    for i in range(1 << 16): # also O(1), but with a large constant
        if i & s == i:
            res += a[i]
    return res
```

Then you'll have a solution in `O(q)` but with constant factor `2^16`, which is larger than the `2^8` in your solution. So how can we optimize the above? First, let's see what exactly happens in each function.

```
def add(s):
    for i in range(1 << 8): # 1 << 8 is just a fancy way of saying 2 ** 8, or 256
        if (i&s) == 0:
            a[s|i] += 1
```

This means that, for each `8` bit number `i`, if that number `AND`ed with `s` is 0 (which means that the two have no set (`1`) bits in common), then we save `s` `OR`d with that number (which means that `s` gets `i`s set bits and also keeps its own). Saving here means incrementing the count at that index.

For example, if `i = 10` in binary:

```
i = 0000 0000 => 10 & i == 0 => a[0000 0010] = 1
i = 0000 0001 => 10 & i == 0 => a[0000 0011] = 1
i = 0000 0010 => 10 & i != 0
i = 0000 0011 => 10 & i != 0
i = 0000 0100 => 10 & i == 0 => a[0000 0110] = 1
...
a[...  **** **1*] = 1
```

After doing this, we have incremented the count of each number that, if `AND`ed with `10`, would result in `10`. So basically, for each addition `s`, we precompute the answer to `cnt(s)`. But at a bit level, so not only `s` is precomputed, but also values with similar bits in the binary representation.

Also, we have counted numbers that are not necessarily added to our list. But we'll fix this later.

```
def delete(s):
    for i in range(1 << 8):
        if (i&s) == 0:
            a[s|i] -= 1
```

This is just the reverse of the above.

```
def cnt(s):
    res = 0
    for i in range(1 << 8):
        if (s|(i<<8)) == s:
            res += a[s & (~(i<<8))]
    return res
```

Here, we need to find out how many numbers `p`, from our list, `AND`ed with `s` remain `p`, and we must do this by only checking `8` bit numbers.

```
if (s | (i << 8)) == s
```

Since `i` is `8` bits, `i << 8` will look like this:

```
i      =           **** ****
i << 8 = **** **** 0000 0000
```

And `s` `OR`ed with this will get more bits added to its last `8` bits (or they will remain the same). For example, if `s = 10`, we'll have:

```
10 | (0 << 8) == 10 => true
10 | (1 << 8) == 10 => false
... the rest should actually all be false
```

Now, we'll increment our count by:

```
a[s & (~(i << 8))]
```

For `i = 0`:

```
i         =           0000 0000
i << 8    = 0000 0000 0000 0000
~(i << 8) = 1111 1111 1111 1111

10 & (~(i << 8)) = 1111 1111 1111 1111 &
                                    10
                 = 0000 0000 0000 0010

a[0000 0000 0000 0010] = 1
```

Basically, this reverses the encoding in `add` and finds our answer. Remember that in `add`, we didn't touch the last `8` bits. Here, we remove those last bits by doing `s & (~(i << 8))` and leave only the numbers in our list.

The intuition behind it is that you can spread the work across the `3` operations. I don't know how to give you an exact deduction. Usually, when you have to work with `n` bit numbers, you can do a lot of counting operations on them by only using `n / 2` bit numbers and `n / 2` operations. I usually just fiddle around with such formulas until something sticks, or I give up and search for the answer. Not very formal, but.

Once you have the solution, understanding it is simply a matter of grasping exactly what the bit operations do. This can take time, but it's a more exact process that will definitely work if you dedicate enough time to it.

For a deeper understanding of why this works, I suggest you add print statements to every part of your methods, which show you exactly what happens and how everything looks like, like how I attempted to do. Then run the program with small inputs.

Another problem that you can solve in a similar fashion is: given a bunch of `32` bit numbers, quickly answer how many set (`1`) bits each one has. Do it in `O(1)` with a constant factor of `2^16`.